# How to load a background image for a div in bootstrap responsive page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need to load a background image for the center `div`.

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">text
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="background:red;color:white">TEXT with background image</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `background:url('url-to-your-image');` to the inline style of the div element

```
<div 
    class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2"
    style="background:red;color:white; background:url('url-to-your-image')"
>TEXT with background image</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that for the image to be visible the div will need either min-height or content to fill in the area.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div style="background-image:url('paper.gif');">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

That's one way of setting the background image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#bgimg {
    background-image: url('paper.gif');
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="bgimg">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

That's another method. Hope it helps!